# How to clear contents of log file already opened by the same Windows process?

Tags: winapi, file-io, process

I have some third party code in the same process in another DLL with no source that's holding open a log file opened with:

```
CreateFile(szFile, GENERIC_WRITE,
         FILE_SHARE_READ,
         NULL, OPEN_ALWAYS,
         FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
         NULL);
```

Is there any way I can clear this log file from within the same process? Calling CreateFile with the same parameters obviously fails because I'm requesting write access and the file only has FILE_SHARE_READ.

Is there way of getting hold of the original handle without requiring admin for enumerating system handles discussed in this post http://forum.sysinternals.com/topic18892.html

Comment: How are you going to do this in the same process, if you don't have source? You are going to inject? Or it is a shell extension.

Comment: I have the source for the application but not the third party DLL (it's a COM server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the DLL does not provide `FILE_SHARE_WRITE` access, then you cannot modify the file, which would include truncating the file with `SetEndOfFile()`.  So you are out of luck unless you modify the DLL.

Comment: and that's true even if I have the source for the process that loaded the DLL? Any way of finding and using the file handle directly?

Comment: The source for the calling process is irrelevant since the source of he DLL is the restricting factor.  And no, you would not be able to get the DLL's open handle to the file unless you enumerate the process's handles.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've decided to work around this by just displaying the recent portions of the logfile rather than modifying the log file.